# JavaFx application works fine on IDE but not as a jar file

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

First of all, my first question here. Found similar problems but either they are not solved or not the same. So here it goes. I have a javafx desktop application. It works just fine on intellij but when i build a .jar file, it doesn't. What i do not understand is why it is trying to find it in C: directory. Shouldn't it be looking for in jar file? How can i fix this?

when i try to run in command prompt it says this:

> ```
> Exception in Application start method
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\src\resources\loginPage.fxml (The 
> system cannot find the path specified)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2440)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
>     at application.Main.start(Main.java:24)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
>     ... 1 more
> Exception running application application.Main
> ```

Comment: The jar cannot find your fxml file

Comment: @smac89 yes exactly. I use java 1.8 so i did not add JavaFx jar file to since it comes with java 1.8. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not copying correctly the resources inside your .jar file or you are calling it wrongly.

This is how you should load it:

```
    stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/ExampleView.fxml"))));
```

This is how you should organise your fxml views inside the resource folder:
[Check this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWrZG.png)

Comment: i am thinking the same thing actually right now.   Scene scene = new Scene(FXML.load(getClass().getResource("src//resources//loginPage.fxml"))); i added this line but i got an error that says, cannot resolve method load in FXML

Comment: OK  i got it. It is not FXML.load , it is FXMLLoader.load() but that did not help either. On Ide, now it says Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.

Comment: You shouldn't include the resource path inside the getResource. You should write it as follow `stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loginPage.fxml"))));`

Sorry, it's FXMLLoader and not FXML, my mistake

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required` , it happens because you are specifying wrongly the pathname.. if it's at the root you should use only `loginPage.fxml` as location. Just check my last answer for full code snippet

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me. For the ones who need it, here is the complete start method i will also edit the question:                                                                          
            public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
  parentWindow = stage;


  Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/loginPage.fxml")));
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();

Comment: @ŞükrüAYDINLIK The `src` folder is not available at runtime - it makes absolutely no sense to have that as part of the path of the FXML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other for a complete discussion.

Comment: @James_D thanks for your help. i cannot believe i still struggle with these after 3 years